# Why is my javascript file not re-setting a div's attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that is adding and removing a class to a couple divs when a link is clicked on.  Each div has a set class that does not need to be removed.  However, said class is being removed.  How do I stop this from happening?

**HTML**

```
<div id="home" class="page pageShowing"></div>
<div id="portfolio" class="page"></div>
```

**JS**

```
let holder = document.getElementById("main");
let pageShowingClass = holder.getElementsByClassName("pageShowing");

let pages = holder.getElementsByClassName("page");

Navigation.Links.forEach(function(value){
    let createNavLink = document.createElement("li");
    let createNavText = document.createTextNode(value.title);
    createNavLink.appendChild(createNavText);
    createNavList.appendChild(createNavLink);

    createNavLink.addEventListener("click", function(){
        let link = createNavLink.innerHTML;
        link = link.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
        let page = document.getElementById(link);
        page.setAttribute("class", "page");
        for(let i = 0; i < pageShowingClass.length; i++){
```

> Here, the click handler should only be removing the pageShowing class
>   if it exists but is also removing the page class

```
            if(pageShowingClass[i].getAttribute("class") == "pageShowing"){
                pageShowingClass[i].removeAttribute("class");
            }
        }
```

> Here, the click handler should be readding the page class when the
>   link is clicked on.

```
        page.setAttribute("class", "page");
        page.setAttribute("class", "pageShowing");
        page.style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

I know it's easier to do this in jQuery, but I don't want it to be in jQuery.  I also already have it to where it will add and remove the `pageShowing` class dynamically, so that's not an issue.

Comment: You're looking for [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` modify, well, the entire attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on the specified element.

Use [`Element.classList.add(String [, String])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), *adds specified class values. If these classes already exist in attribute of the element, then they are ignored.*

```
page.classList.add('page', 'pageShowing')
```

Answer (score 1):

As Siguza said in the reply, you're removing the class attribute, which is what you DON'T want to be doing in this case.

Let's put the element in question here for reference:

```
<div id="home" class="page pageShowing"></div>
```

`class` is an attribute of the element `div`. When you call `removeAttribute('class')`, it will do as it says:

```
<div id="home"></div>
```

If you check the element in chrome's dev tools or whatever you use, you'll be seeing the element as it says above.

You're probably looking for `Element.className` to modify your classes, so instead of

```
if(pageShowingClass[i].getAttribute("class") == "pageShowing"){
    pageShowingClass[i].removeAttribute("class");
}
```

you'll want

```
if(pageShowingClass[i].getAttribute("class") == "pageShowing"){
    pageShowingClass[i].className = "page";
}
```

and if you want to add the `pageShowing` class again, you'd just say `pageShowingClass[i].className = "page pageShowing"`